# Automatically populate columns with Person/Group Mobile Number SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

Im creating a simple contact list and im looking at ways to ensure theres little oppourtunity for the end users to enter incorrect information when i hand it back over to them.

One thing idea i was speculating about was the idea of having the user enter the persons name into a person/group column and then the mobile number column & email address column would be populated with that persons details that are stored under their name.

One idea i had for this was to set up the mobile phone number & email address columns as person/group columns and setting up a workflow that that says, when the end user is entering a new item or editing one, the form will only show one person/group column where they enter the name of the person theyre looking to add. The workflow would then set this same value in the mobile & email columns, which have been set to display as mobile number and work email respectively.

Should also point out im using sharepoint online with SPD 2013

Im still newish to sharepoint so im not too sure how the functionality and general syntax involved in creating this workflow/ if this would even work!

Any advice or help would be most appreciated!